# Forms authentication failed: The ticket supplied is not valid

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies

We have two web sites. One ASP.NET MVC 3 and one ASP.NET 4 Web Forms. Each web site has its own .NET 4 Integrated Application pool which is run under "Application Pool Identity" user's rights.

What we want to do is to share the ASP.NET authentication cookie between two sites (please keep reading!). We have given the two sites same machine keys (in web.config files) with the same encryption types and .NET 2-compatible cookies etc as well as same application names to both sites. Thus when a user logs in to one site, the authentication cookie is shared with the other site so users do not have to login to a site when they are logged in to the other one.

This perfectly works on several development machines and on our staging and live servers. However, it does not work on the client's production server! I checked the server's event log and I found this error message only: "Forms authentication failed: The ticket supplied is not valid!".

I read tens of blog posts and forum discussions such as the two ones below but none helped:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/09/16/forms-authentication-fails-after-installing-iis-7-5.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/30/asp-net-security-fix-now-on-windows-update.aspx

I also put these two lines in the web.config (under `<appSettings>`:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption" value="true" />
<add key="aspnet:UseLegacyMachineKeyEncryption" value="true" />
```

I also set the app. pool user of both app. pools to Net_Work service, unchecked the "Auto Generate Keys" in under IIS/Machine key etc. but still ASP.NET is refusing the authentication ticket.

Can someone please help me with this? Here is the server's configraiton:

IIS: version 7.5
Windows: 2008 RS sp 1 64x

Comment: This is almost a year old, but I'm having practically the identical problem. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Yes I did. The domain name attribute in <membership tag must be identical between all sites. e.g.:  .mydomain.com  - this allows you to have  site1.mydomain.com and site2.mydomain.com